# Indexing inside a double `for` loop wrongly

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, indexing

I am posting below a simplified code version which reproduces my issue:

```
import numpy as np

a1 = np.array([[0., (2/3)**(1/2), (1/3)**(1/2)],
           [-(1/2)**(1/2), -(1/6)**(1/2), (1/3)**(1/2)],
           [-(1/2)**(1/2), (1/6)**(1/2), -(1/3)**(1/2)],
           [(1/2)**(1/2), -(1/6)**(1/2), (1/3)**(1/2)],
           [(1/2)**(1/2), (1/6)**(1/2), -(1/3)**(1/2)],
           [0., -(2/3)**(1/2), -(1/3)**(1/2)]])

b1 = np.array([[-1. , 0., 0.],
           [-1/2, (3/4)**(1/2), 0.],
           [1/2, -(1/12)**(1/2), -(2/3)**(1/2)],
           [-1/2, -(3/4)**(1/2), 0.],
           [-1/2, -(1/12)**(1/2), -(2/3)**(1/2)],
           [0., (1/3)**(1/2), -(2/3)**(1/2)]])

a2 = np.array([[(1/2)**(1/2), (1/6)**(1/2), -(1/3)**(1/2)],
           [0., -(2/3)**(1/2), -(1/3)**(1/2)],
           [(1/2)**(1/2), -(1/6)**(1/2), (1/3)**(1/2)],
           [-(1/2)**(1/2), (1/6)**(1/2), -(1/3)**(1/2)],
           [0., (2/3)**(1/2), (1/3)**(1/2)],
           [-(1/2)**(1/2), -(1/6)**(1/2), (1/3)**(1/2)]])

b2 = np.array([[1/2 , -(3/4)**(1/2), 0.],
           [-1., 0., 0.],
           [-1/2, (1/12)**(1/2), (2/3)**(1/2)],
           [-1/2, -(3/4)**(1/2), 0.],
           [0., -(1/3)**(1/2), (2/3)**(1/2)],
           [1/2, (1/12)**(1/2), (2/3)**(1/2)]])


avector = [a1, a2]
bvector = [b1, b2]

cvector = [np.zeros([6, 3])]*2

for i in range(2):
    for j in range(6):
        cvector[i][j] = np.cross(avector[i][j], bvector[i][j])
        print(i, j, cvector[i][j])

print(cvector)
```

The output would be:

```
0 0 [ 0.         -0.57735027  0.81649658]
0 1 [-0.5        -0.28867513 -0.81649658]
0 2 [-0.5       -0.8660254  0.       ]
0 3 [ 0.5        -0.28867513 -0.81649658]
0 4 [-0.5        0.8660254  0.       ]
0 5 [ 1.  0.  0.] 
1 0 [-0.5        -0.28867513 -0.81649658]
1 1 [ 0.          0.57735027 -0.81649658]
1 2 [-0.5       -0.8660254  0.       ]
1 3 [-0.5         0.28867513  0.81649658]
1 4 [ 1.  0. -0.]
1 5 [-0.5        0.8660254  0.       ]

[array([[-0.5       , -0.28867513, -0.81649658],
       [ 0.        ,  0.57735027, -0.81649658],
       [-0.5       , -0.8660254 ,  0.        ],
       [-0.5       ,  0.28867513,  0.81649658],
       [ 1.        ,  0.        , -0.        ],
       [-0.5       ,  0.8660254 ,  0.        ]]),
array([[-0.5       , -0.28867513, -0.81649658],
       [ 0.        ,  0.57735027, -0.81649658],
       [-0.5       , -0.8660254 ,  0.        ],
       [-0.5       ,  0.28867513,  0.81649658],
       [ 1.        ,  0.        , -0.        ],
       [-0.5       ,  0.8660254 ,  0.        ]])]
```

One can note that the first line `0 0` calculated inside the `for` loop does not match with the matrix `cvector[0][0]`. I would hope they matched. The same happens with the sixth line `0 5` and the matrix `cvector[0][0]`.

If you change the `range(2)` to `range(1)` in the first `for` loop, you will not see the same behavior and, in my opinion, the correct one.

Does anyone know why it is happening?

Comment: Could you provide the expected output? It's a bit hard to understand what you are trying to do and to verify the calculations. Also, you are not using numpy's vectorization. Have you tried to do `cvector = np.cross(avector, bvector)`? It seems to give exactly the result you find in the for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create `cvector` using `[np.zeros([6, 3])]*2`, you are not creating 2 `np.array`'s. The second instance is simply a view of the first. So, `cvector[0] = cvector[1]`. Thus, in the loop, you overwrite the `i=0` calculations when you do it again for `i=1`.

Instead, you can create two independent arrays, like so:

```
cvector = [np.zeros([6, 3]), np.zeros([6, 3])]
```

and it works as expected:

```
(0, 0, array([ 0.        , -0.57735027,  0.81649658]))
(0, 1, array([-0.5       , -0.28867513, -0.81649658]))
(0, 2, array([-0.5      , -0.8660254,  0.       ]))
(0, 3, array([ 0.5       , -0.28867513, -0.81649658]))
(0, 4, array([-0.5      ,  0.8660254,  0.       ]))
(0, 5, array([1., 0., 0.]))
(1, 0, array([-0.5       , -0.28867513, -0.81649658]))
(1, 1, array([ 0.        ,  0.57735027, -0.81649658]))
(1, 2, array([-0.5      , -0.8660254,  0.       ]))
(1, 3, array([-0.5       ,  0.28867513,  0.81649658]))
(1, 4, array([ 1.,  0., -0.]))
(1, 5, array([-0.5      ,  0.8660254,  0.       ]))

[array([[ 0.        , -0.57735027,  0.81649658],
       [-0.5       , -0.28867513, -0.81649658],
       [-0.5       , -0.8660254 ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.5       , -0.28867513, -0.81649658],
       [-0.5       ,  0.8660254 ,  0.        ],
       [ 1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ]]),
 array([[-0.5       , -0.28867513, -0.81649658], 
       [ 0.        ,  0.57735027, -0.81649658],
       [-0.5       , -0.8660254 ,  0.        ],
       [-0.5       ,  0.28867513,  0.81649658],
       [ 1.        ,  0.        , -0.        ],
       [-0.5       ,  0.8660254 ,  0.        ]])]
```

---

Consider this example to show why the first array is being overwritten:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: cvector = [np.zeros([6, 3])]*2

In [3]: cvector
Out[3]: 
[array([[0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]]), 
 array([[0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]])]

In [4]: cvector[0][0] = (1, 2, 3)

In [5]: cvector
Out[5]: 
[array([[1., 2., 3.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]]), 
 array([[1., 2., 3.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]])]
```

Note how the first element is overwritten in both cases.